# Create a new column based by Iterating over consecutive rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,20,3,4,50,6],
               'b':[12,43,78,23,14,28],
               'c': [100,200,300,400,500,600]})`
```

I want to iterate over consecutive rows such that,

if next row's `'a'` value **-** current row's `'a'` value is **less than 10**,

and then check if next row's `'c'` value **-** current row's `'b'` is **less than 400**

```
return 0

else return Nan.
```

I wanted to do it using `.apply` have written a code for it.

```
def query(row,df):
    try:
        i = row.name
        curr = df.iloc[i]
        curr_a = curr['a']
        next = df.iloc[i+1]
       next_a = next['a']
        if (next_a-curr_a) < 10:
            print(next_a,curr_a)
            curr_b = curr['b']
            next_c = next['c']
            print(next_c,curr_b)
           if (next_c - curr_b) < 400:
                return 0
        else:
            diff = np.nan
        return diff
    except:
        pass
```

`df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda x: query(x,df),axis=1)`

Basically I am taking index of the current row i.e `i`, and passing it to a function where I am locating the current row using `df.iloc[i]`
and next row using `df.iloc[i+1]` and then checking the conditions. But I don't think it is the best way to do it.

Is there a better way to do this? May be using `.shift` or any pythonic way? Any leads will be helpful.

Comment: Definitely .shift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `np.where` with `shift`

```
np.where(((df.a.shift(-1)-df.a)<10)&((df.c.shift(-1)-df.b)<400),0,np.NaN)
Out[85]: array([nan,  0.,  0., nan, nan, nan])
```